# При попытке селекта, выпадает ошибка о необходимости указать DRIVER ID

Tags: delphi, sqlite3, delphi-10-seattle

Пытаюсь сделать `select` из sqlite базы, выпадает ошибка о необходимости указать `DRIVER ID`

```
GeneralForm.FDConnection1.DriverName:='SQlite';
GeneralForm.FDConnection1.Params.DriverID:='SQlite';
GeneralForm.FDConnection1.Open('select * from quotes;');
```

При этом через ExecSql `INSERT` и `DELETE` работают.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, хотя FDConnection1 и имеет функцию ExecSql, функция open отличается от fdquery.open и отвечает за открытие соединения.

Comment: Так и какое же решение у вопроса?